# from WPF to ASP.NET where do I start?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been developning c# app in WPF for a few years now and I wanna start doing webapps in ASP.NET but I've now Idea where to start. Can anyone gimme some gudiance on where to start?

Answer (score 2):

You may start here: http://asp.net or more precisely here: http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: What I meant to say is that I'm pretty confused about which features to learn first. Which features would you guys recommend? I'm pretty good at HTML & CSS btw..

Comment: @Ols1, if you are good at HTML and CSS I would recommend you learning the HTTP protocol specification. Then you could move on to ASP.NET. Javascript might also be useful if you want to create more dynamic web sites.